# error displaying when trying to error capture

Tags: python

I am having the problem where i need some code to be error captioned, so if the user does **not** enter a **number** it should tell them that they have done something wrong. Below is the code that i would like to error capture, and i am not sure how to do about doing this.

```
        if cmd in ('L', 'LEFT'):
            Left_position = (int(input("How many places would you like to move left")))
            if args:
                step = int(args[0])
            else:
                step = Left_position
            y -= step
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Left_position = (int(input("How many places would you like to move left")))
```

Will throw an error if the input is not a string that can be turned into an integer. To capture this, surround this with a try block:

```
try:
    Left_position = (int(input("How many places would you like to move left")))
except ValueError:
    print('Error is handled here')
if args:
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rearrange your code slightly. As far as I can see, you only actually want to ask the user for input if `args` haven't been provided. If this is the case, the following should work:

```
if args:
    step = int(args[0])
else:
    while True:
        try:
            Left_position = (int(input("How many places would you like to move left")))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print 'This is not an integer! Please try again'
    step = Left_position
y -= step
```

First, if there are `args` we use the first element and carry on. If there aren't, we enter a (potentially infinite) loop where the user is asked to provide an input. If this is not wrappable as an integer, an error message is printed and then the user is asked again for an input value. This terminates once an integer is provided - the `break` line can only be reached if an error isn't thrown by the input.